# Why does Android Soft Keyboard close when I press "Enter" (and not make a newline)

Tags: java, android, android-softkeyboard

The android soft keyboard is toggled from the context menu via

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
```

It types text fine, but when the Enter is pressed, the keyboard closes. Nothing is capture in `onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)`

The layout looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3aINv.png).

**Extra Info:** For those wondering, the keyboard input is being sent over a TCP connection, not into any view within the layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright so this question got no attention  but I'm going to put my solution here in case someone else has this problem.

For some reason Android has decided that after typing text (with no EditText around) the Enter key is now an action button and not a newline key.

I managed to capture input by receiving key presses in `dispatchKeyEvent()` rather than `onKeyPress()`

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent ke)
{

    int unicode = ke.getUnicodeChar();
    if (ke.getAction() == 0 && ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) // getAction() returns 1 (up) or 0 (down). 
    {
        // do my work here
        return true; // end here (doesn't go to onKeyDown())
    } else
    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(ke);
}
```

this event is fired **twice** on key press so it was important to use getAction() in the if statement. For all other keyboard presses, I used onKeyDown() which is why it was important to return `super.dispatchKeyEvent(ke);` if it wasn't the Enter key.

Answer (score 0):

Check your xml may be you set maxline=1 or may be give singleLine="true"

Comment: There is no EditText in the layout. The keyboard is not inserting text anywhere (I am using the key presses for something else). Have updated the question with a link to the layout. Thanks for the reply!